# SQL SUMMING A COLUMN

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in oracle 
Table: Mark

```
 id  |   subject |    points 
---- | ------    |   ------ 
2    |  math    |   35
2   |   english  |  40
2     | science   | 30
3    |   math    |  30
3    |  english  |   20
3    |  science |   10
```

What will will the Query if i need `35+40+30 =105`
Is it

```
Select sum(points) from Mark where ID = '2';   ???
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: Seems fine. Or do a GROUP BY.

Comment: Have you tried you query?

Comment: Please do not compare strings with numbers. `'2'` is a string, not a number. You statement should use a proper number to compare with the id: `where ID = 2;`

Comment: Why not just execute it and find out?

Answer (score 1):

You already have the solution :)

If you have to *SUM* all the *points* for the id = 2
that is the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum every id:

```
select id, sum(points) 
from Mark 
group by id
```